# Неправильное позиционирование элементов в сафари

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

Всем привет. Есть у меня каруселька с элементами. Все работает, отображается хорошо во всех браузерах за исключением сафари - там почему-то кнопки навигации скачут туда-сюда, т.е. изначально разбросаны в разные стороны, а при наведении начинают дергаться и состыковываться между собой. По субъективным ощущениям дело в позиционировании `left: auto;` когда убираю - в сафари они состыковываются, но неправильно отображаются все равно..

```js
     $('#foot-carousel').owlCarousel({
       items: 3,
       pagination: false,
       navigation: true,
       navigationText: ["", ""],
     });
```

```css
#foot-carousel .owl-carousel {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.cart-carusel {
  position: relative;
}
#foot-carousel .li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #5f636a;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
#foot-carousel div a {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#foot-carousel .cart-quantity a {
  color: #292f38;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
#foot-carousel .product-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-pagination {
  display: none!important;
}
.cart-carusel {
  position: relative;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-prev,
#foot-carousel .owl-next {
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s aese;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-prev:hover,
#foot-carousel .owl-next:hover {
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-prev:before,
#foot-carousel .owl-next:before {
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #696e6e;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-prev:hover:before,
#foot-carousel .owl-next:hover:before {
  color: #fff;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-prev {
  left: auto;
  right: 50px;
}
#foot-carousel .owl-next {
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foot-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">
  <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
    <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 2520px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 0ms ease; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 315px;">
        <div class="li">
          <a href="#">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="#" class="attachment-60x60 wp-post-image" alt="item-3">
          </a>
          <div class="product-text">
            <span class="sku">Product SKU N/A</span>
            <span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">80.000 руб</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 315px;">
        <div class="li">
          <a href="#">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="#" class="attachment-60x60 wp-post-image" alt="item-3">
          </a>
          <div class="product-text">
            <span class="sku">Product SKU N/A</span>
            <span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">80.000 руб</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 315px;">
        <div class="li">
          <a href="#">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="#" class="attachment-60x60 wp-post-image" alt="item-3">
          </a>
          <div class="product-text">
            <span class="sku">Product SKU N/A</span>
            <span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">80.000 руб</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="owl-item" style="width: 315px;">
        <div class="li">
          <a href="#">
            <img width="60" height="60" src="#" class="attachment-60x60 wp-post-image" alt="item-3">
          </a>
          <div class="product-text">
            <span class="sku">Product SKU N/A</span>
            <span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">80.000 руб</span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-controls clickable">
    <div class="owl-buttons">
      <div class="owl-prev"></div>
      <div class="owl-next"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант - в safari могут появляться прыжки из-за толщины текстовых элементов (на маке шрифты чуть толще). Если у вас там где-то текст впритык, то может повлиять.

Comment: @IonDen я не думаю, что в этом дело - кнопки расположены над элементами и не могут особо влиять на них

Comment: медиа запрос если сафари лупани и поправь что вылазит.

Comment: @Legowarriors это как? `media safari {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cssFix = function(){
  var u = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
  addClass = function(el,val){
    if(!el.className) {
      el.className = val;
    } else {
      var newCl = el.className;
      newCl+=(" "+val);
      el.className = newCl;
    }
  },
  is = function(t){return (u.indexOf(t)!=-1)};
  addClass(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],[
    (!(/opera|webtv/i.test(u))&&/msie (\d)/.test(u))?('ie ie'+RegExp.$1)
      :is('firefox/2')?'gecko ff2'
      :is('firefox/3')?'gecko ff3'
      :is('gecko/')?'gecko'
      :is('opera/9')?'opera opera9':/opera (\d)/.test(u)?'opera opera'+RegExp.$1
      :is('konqueror')?'konqueror'
      :is('applewebkit/')?'webkit safari'
      :is('mozilla/')?'gecko':'',
    (is('x11')||is('linux'))?' linux'
      :is('mac')?' mac'
      :is('win')?' win':''
  ].join(" "));
}();
```

А теперь о том, как этим скриптом пользоваться.
Первое, что нужно сделать — вставить скрипт на страницу :) Далее правим только CSS.

Теперь у нас в рапоряжении есть дополнительные css селекторы, а именно ОС и браузер. То есть, конструкция будет выглядеть так:
.[ОС].[Браузер] css селектор

Селекторы ОСи:
.win — Windows
.linux — Linux
.mac — MacOS

Селекторы браузеров:

```
.ie — все версии ИЕ
.ie8 — ИЕ 8.х
.ie7 — ИЕ 7.x
.ie6 — ИЕ 6.x
.ie5 — ИЕ 5.x
.gecko — все версии фаерфокса, и остальные гекко-браузеры
.ff2 — фаерфокс 2
.ff3 — фаерфокс 3
.opera — все версии оперы
.opera8 — опера 8.x
.opera9 — опера 9.x
.konqueror — konqueror
.safari — сафари
```

Возвращаясь в абстрактной ситуации с фаерфоксом на маке, решение будет такое:

```
.mac.gecko селектор{/* исправленный код */}
или
.mac.ff2(3) селектор{/* исправленный код */}
```

Стоит отметить приоритеты селекторов. Разберем на примере ФФ3:

```
.win.ff3 #id{background: #aaa} /* 1 */
.win.gecko #id{background: #f00} /* 2 */
.ff3 #id{background:#333} /* 3 */
.gecko #id{background:#00f} /* 4 */
.win #id{background: #ff0} /* 5 */
```